# What's the corresponding call for create-status in github3.py API?

Tags: github3.py

In `githubV3`, we have a way to [create status](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#create-a-status) for branches (refs). I want to perform this call using `github3.py`. I am using `version 0.9.3.` Can I do that?

Comment: I would use version 1.0, but it seems it broke backward compatibility with 0.9.3, so several applications would stop running if I did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you [quickly search](https://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/search.html?q=create_status&check_keywords=yes&area=default) the documentation, you'll see that you can [create statuses for Repositories](https://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/repos.html?highlight=create_status#github3.repos.repo.Repository.create_status) and [create statuses for Deployments](https://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/repos.html?highlight=create_status#github3.repos.deployment.Deployment.create_status).

The former allows you to specify a SHA (which would be the HEAD of the branch), e.g.,

```
repo.create_status(head_of_my_branch, state='error')
```

Comment: ouch, not sure how I wasn't able to find this. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. I try to name things in github3.py sensibly so that searching for them works well. That's why I included the search link (to show you an example search for future queries)